# Firestore data modeling and querying for a Tinder-like app

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

To make things simpler, let's say the app has only 2 entities: the `user` and the `post` which are contents created by users.

Users can do 3 things:

1. create posts
2. swipe on posts, like or dislike
3. unfollow the author of a post so that he/she will no longer see posts from the author

My question is: how to query `posts` based on whether if the author is unfollowed by me?

### My 1st approach to model the data

```
users/{userId}
- userId

posts/{postId}
- author <userId>
- content

unfollows/{userId}
- userId
- unfollowedUserId

likes/{postId_userId}
- postId
- userId

dislikes/{postId_userId}
- postId
- userId
```

Querying posts:

```
// get all userIds that I unfollow

const unfollows = collection('unfollows').where('userId', '==', 'myUserId');
```

But then I don't know how to query `posts` with the `unfollows` which is an array of user ids efficiently.

```
// This doesn't seem correct and
// I don't know how to write the `where` filters programmatically:

// assume unfollows is already sorted.
const unfollows = collection('posts')
  .where('author', '<', unfollows[0]).where('author', '>', unfollows[0])
  .where('author', '<', unfollows[1]).where('author', '>', unfollows[1])
  ...
```

### 2nd approach

Adding the `unfollowedBy` field in `posts` which is a map of users unfollowing the author and populated upon `post` creation and updated upon new `unfollows`.

```
users/{userId}
- userId

posts/{postId}
- author <userId>
- content
- unfollowedBy <Map with userIds as keys>

unfollows/{userId}
- userId
- unfollowedUserId

likes/{postId_userId}
- postId
- userId

dislikes/{postId_userId}
- postId
- userId
```

This allowed me to query `posts` with:

```
collection('posts').where(`unfollowedUserId.${myUserId}`, '==', null);
```

However, there are some issues in this approach:

1. `unfollowedBy` in a `post` doc does not scale since the size of `unfollowedBy` is proportional to the size of the userbase. I know for anything that's going to grow to an unbounded size should be a subcollection instead of a map in the doc but by making `unfollowedBy` a subcollection I cannot query `posts` with it anymore.
2. The `post` doc will be updated frequently if the author is being unfollowed frequently in order to keep the `unfollowedBy` map up-to-date.
3. Any user would require permission to update the `unfollowedBy` field of other's posts, which is not ideal, or I'll have to create a cloud function to handle unfollows.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I'm having the same type of issue.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that firestore simply isn't suited for this kind of app =/